# Bug in FFmpeg build allows GPL filter use from an LGPL build can I distribute FFMPEG as LGPL

Tags: lgpl, gpl-2, ffmpeg

I have build ffmpeg (4.3) libraries configured for LGPL on multiple OS's looking to be called from my own code using ffmpeg filters to deinterleave video.
below is the configure command.

```
./configure --disable-static --enable-shared --disable-iconv --disable-libxcb --disable-zlib --disable-bzlib --disable-lzma --disable-doc --disable-debug --disable-x86asm --disable-asm --enable-filter=bwdif --enable-filter=w3fdif
```

However testing out the filters even though not enabled I can call the yadif filter and various other filters that are GPL

Given the ffmpeg build lists itself as LGPL am I allow to redistribute - or is given the bug in ffmpeg build options would this violate there licensing.
Note the GPL filters are not called from my code.

Comment: Which license applies depends on the contents of the binary, NOT on the build options. If you get GPL parts without `--enable-gpl` that's a bug in ffmpeg. But are you *sure* that yadif is still GPL? This seems to have [changed in 2014](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/commit/194ef56ba7e659196fe554782d797b1b45c3915f).

Comment: Thanks for the advice about build's that's good to know!
Honestly thought yadif was GPL still (having trouble finding information)- my builds will fail stating GPL not enabled if I try and enable the yadif filter (explicit). 
Though from your commit link that predates my ffmpeg version.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean that "the ffmpeg build lists itself as LGPL"? Not selecting the build option `--enable-gpl` is not enough to guarantee that you'll get an LGPL-compliant binary. See FFmpeg's Licence Compliance Checklist here:  https://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html

Comment: See also the page https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/md_LICENSE.html which lists all GPL files. You could use that list to verify that the binary does not contain code from any of those files. Another possibility would be to add `#error` preprocessing directives to those files to force a build failure in case they "accidentally" get compiled in the build process. Maybe that's overkill, though. It's possible that the files normally get compiled but are not linked into the executable without `--enable-gpl`, so that would be fine as well.

Comment: To make this more useful for future reference, please also mention which version of FFmpeg you are building.

Comment: Hi Brandin - thanks for the feedback 
 I have edited the question to mentioned its 4.3 the ffmpeg version I used and will shortly edit my answer to be a bit more clear referring to of gpl files to and more explicitly state the response.

Answer (score 2):

So the short answer would be no I can not distrubute the Code if it has GPL functionality thanks to AMON for answering.

The responsibility of checking wether the code is LGPL is on the distributor -  ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/md_LICENSE.html which lists all GPL files (thanks Brandin) can be compared to see which files were used by checking the logs created when compiling to see the linked files.

In regards to yadif - as I am using a version of ffmpeg that has since changed it to LGPL it is available to distribute.

in regards to other various other filters I found manually disabling the --disable-"filter" removed them from the builds.
Again checking the list of complied files to ensure no GPL files were used.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If the answer depends on comments, I think you should restate the relevant information from the comments in your Answer. Right now, a user would find it more useful just to read the comments on their own. An Answer should really stand on its own as a useful information resource. Another problem with your Answer is that in the original question, you also mentioned "various other filters that are GPL" in addition to yadif. So, if I understood the comment correctly, the license issue with yadif is now solved, but it's not clear how you solved the license issue with the "various other filters".